# Resize a UIView to the size of its UILabel subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I would like to create a UIView that looks something like this:

[image: The label "Tag" inside a rounded rectangle.]

I would like this view to always resize itself to the text inside it. I tried something like this:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TagView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var tagTitle: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView() {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = tagTitle
        addSubview(label)

        layer.cornerRadius = 15
        frame = CGRect(origin: frame.origin, size: sizeThatFits(label.frame.size))
    }

}
```

But this doesn't change the `frame` of the view at all. I think the reason is that Auto Layout is enabled.

What can I do to achieve this effect? Am I approaching this from the wrong perspective?

Answer (score 0):

try this code for setUpView() method

```
 func setUpView() {
     let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
     label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
     label.text = tagTitle
     label.layer.masksToBounds = true
     label.layer.cornerRadius = 15
     self.view.addSubview(label)

        }
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. I don't even see the `UILabel` at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add width constraint of view to equal width to label. Similarly do it for height.

Comment: When I do that, and also use `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, it kind of works, but then it doesn't keep its place on the screen anymore, it's positioned to (0, 0).

Comment: Also add vertical and horizontal constraint